# C# export to excel replace <br/> with a line break in a cell

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I'm exporting data to excel. Is it possible to replace `<br/>` in a string with a line break (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>) so that when exported to excel the string is displayed on separate lines in the same cell.

For example:

```
string text = "Number One" + "`<br/>`" + "Number Two"
```

Excel:

```
Number One
Number Two
```

Answer (score 4):

Only what you need it's add `style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"` inside `<br />` tag.
Data will be displayed on separate lines but in the same cell.

```
<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string textWithNewLine = text.Replace("<br/>", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: @Roslyn make sure you have `Cells[x, y].Style.IsTextWrapped = true;` for the cell.

Comment: I'm exporting the data using a gridview.